# Rest response bean extends Map

Tags: java, json, spring

In a spring rest application context, i'm trying to create a generic response bean.

The purpose is to avoid to create a specific bean for each method.

I'd like to use standard fields, like status and message, by binding various properties to a map.

Consider the following example :

```
public class ResponseRestDefault extends HashMap {
    private String status;
    private String message;

    public ResponseRestDefault() {
    }

    public void addParam(String key, String value) {
        this.put(key, value);
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
@RequestMapping(value = "response", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseRestDefault> response() {

    ResponseRestDefault response = new ResponseRestDefault();

    response.setStatus("success");
    response.setMessage("ok");
    response.addParam("test", "value");

    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

Json result :

```
{
    "test": "value"
}
```

Does the json result could contain map fields and class properties ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: It is ignoring your fields because the container just checks if this is a Hashmap, if so iterates through the key/value pairs. If you want a generic response make it really simple. Maybe string

Comment: it makes sense.. maybe i'll use a composition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your response class. Make sure you have the getter and setter methods for map.

```
public class ResponseRestDefault {
  private String status;
  private String message;
  private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

  public ResponseRestDefault() {
  }

  public void setMap(String key, String value) {
    map.put(key, value);
  }

  public Map<String, String> getMap()
  {
    return map;
  }

  public String getStatus() {
      return status;
  }

  public void setStatus(String status) {
      this.status = status;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
      return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
  }
}
```

You will get response in below format :

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "ok",
    "map": {
        "test": "value"
    }
}
```